# Radio Button within a table with CDK Table / Material Design

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat, angular-cdk

I am actually trying to insert a radio button group within a table component of  CDK Table /material design .
[See Expected Image /Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTpOp.png)

https://stackblitz.com/angular/qxkmjjxrlrm?file=app%2Ftable-sticky-header-example.ts

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: I want to use the radio buttons instead of the checkbox.Please see this Image 
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTpOp.png

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add your radio group around your table, and add radio buttons inside your cells. [Here's a StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4hdgvd?file=app%2Ftable-radio-group-example.html).

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selectedElement">

  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- Selected Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="selected">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        Selected Element:<br /><b>{{ selectedElement?.name }}</b>
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <mat-radio-button [value]="element">
        </mat-radio-button>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    ...

  </table>

</mat-radio-button>
```